# How to display git changes on window power shell

Tags: git, powershell

I just factory reset my laptop and reinstalled Git, but there a slight change. Before whenever I make a changes to my app, the un-added changes would show as a red number next to my app's name in window power shell, or show green if added (git add .), but its no longer does that which is really annoying. Does anyone know how I get that feature back?

Comment: I've already tried uninstalling and re-installing with the various different options. I've also looking for the answers but had no luck, if anyone has a clue please help

Comment: Did you forget to install `posh-git`?

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Comment: Some git clients include it (GitHub for Windows does), but I don't think it's installed in the default modules folder, so it won't autoload in a normal powershell session

Comment: eh anyway i can upvote u? somehwere?

Comment: I'll post an answer soon

Answer (score 0):

Posting the solution which is based on the comment above made by `@Mathias R. Jessen`.

You will need to install `posh-git` to make it work.

#### `posh-git`

> A PowerShell environment for Git http://dahlbyk.github.io/posh-git/